# 2D Triangle in SlimDX

Tags: c#, graphics, geometry, 2d, slimdx

How to draw a triangle using SlimDX's Direct2D interface given triangle vertices are given in pixel coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We just recently added a sample covering this topic to our repository. The relevant source file is [here](http://code.google.com/p/slimdx/source/browse/trunk/samples/Direct2D/SimpleTriangle2D/SimpleTriangle2D.cs).

Answer (score 1):

You want to draw primitive with "Transformed" coordinates.

Transformed meams they are already in Screen X,Y so DirectX wont project them.

Comment: Not really what I was looking form - I'm using Direct2D so there is no projection at all.

Comment: Yes, thats what Transformed coordinates are, as if you already transformed them to 2D.  Even if you are just using 2d coords to begin with, it's the same thing